# GraphQL, ReactJs - unable to retrieve data when passing parameter to Query

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, graphql, schema

I'd like to retrieve the `_id` of a document in my mongodb database using a graphql query.

Here is my query:

```
query {
  getTeamRegistrationID(teamName:"Patriots") {
    _id
  }
}
```

And the result:

```
{
  "data": {
    "getTeamRegistrationID": []
  }
}
```

This should return the ObjectID of the document from the mongodb database.

Here's my graphql schema:

```
const typeDefs = gql`
    type TeamRegistration {
        _id: ID,
        teamName: String
    },
    type Query {
        getTeamRegistrationID(teamName: String): [TeamRegistration]
    }`
```

My resolver:

```
const resolvers = {
    Query: {
        getTeamRegistrationID: (parent, teamRegistration) => TeamRegistration.find({ teamName: teamRegistration.teamName })
    }
}
```

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong here. Is there something I'm missing? Thanks in advance!

Comment: The first thing i'd do is find out what `TeamRegistration.find({ teamName: teamRegistration.teamName })` is actually returning. Is it what you expect or is it something else?

Comment: So I tired the query again, and it works fine! I didnt change anything. I'm not sure what happened the first time around. Thanks tho!